# How to get mails on Google apps and Primary domain

Tags: google-workspace, email, g-suite-administrator

I have a domain lets call in xyz.com. i signed up with google.com and have been using there free apps business version for a while.

I have set up my user accounts on  google and getting mail on that. Now i want to remain those email addresses with google and want to create new one on my domain using the cpanel. but when i do that i am unable to receive any email on those address. As my domain MX records are pointing towards google servers... :(

So what should i do to receive those mail...

Comment: Change the MX records to point to the new mail server\

Answer (score 1):

You could set up *split delivery*, so that you're still using Google's MX servers, but Google will forward all mail to non-Gmail-users to another destination.

See [the Google documentation](https://support.google.com/a/answer/173534?hl=en).

You may also find something useful in this question: [Google Apps for business email forwarding](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/33276/21583)