# Is it possible to run both Outlook and Google Apps on the same domain?

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, google-workspace-for-business, outlook

My company uses Outlook for email/calendars but I'm a big Google Apps user and was wondering if it's possible to implement Google Apps for my company so there can be a choice if someone wants to use Google's apps or Outlook.

Comment: Aside of it being possible or not, you should not allow many different IT infrastructures. It will cost more money in the long run simply because it will be a pain to manage. You have to keep track who uses what and if you allow this, soon people will request other apps such as Thunderbird. Where do you draw the line?

Comment: Google Apps =/= Outlook. Regardless, what makes you think it wouldn't be "possible"?  What actual problem are you running into while implementing it?

Comment: I mean this is off topic, but personally I think companies should move towards a federated app ecosystem. So similar to how companies let their employees choose their hardware (mac or pc), employees should be able to choose the software they want to use as long as it integrates with all other options.

Comment: When i converted to Google Mail from Exchange Server 2003 we used GAME( Google Apps for Microsoft Exchange ... might have been another letter in there) which was installed to allow Outlook to interface with Google mail. I think its called [Google App Sync](https://tools.google.com/dlpage/gappssync) now

Comment: To provide the best answer, you need to provide more details. When you say your company uses "Outlook" what mail server technology is Outlook connecting to? Is it Microsoft Exchange Server? Or is it just some ISP giving your POP3/IMAP access?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Apps for business email forwarding](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/31990/google-apps-for-business-email-forwarding)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to setup a split delivery scenario where email traffic is sent to primary email system. You users are split on different email systems, for example Exchange and Google Apps. If the primary email system have the user, it will send the email to the secondary email system for delivery. This is a very common scenario in Google Apps enterprise setup.

It's also possible to setup dual delivery where emails are delivered to two email systems at once. A scenario suited for backup or transformation from one system to another.

https://support.google.com/a/answer/96855?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

I've seen GMail used as a client for an Exchange server through POP3.  You simply need to enable the Microsoft Exchange POP3 service on the Exchange server.  This will not sync your calendar, though.

Answer (score 0):

I know many companies that use Google Apps as their platform and Outlook as the client. If your company is using Exchange Server, then the change will be less likely to occur. If your Outlook is connect to an ISP e-mail via POP3 or IMAP, then changing to Google Apps will be very easy to do.