# Is it possible to forward only a specific email account to Google Apps?

Tags: gmail, google-workspace-for-business

My client has 5 email accounts.

1. judith@myclient.com
2. carla@myclient.com
3. billy@myclient.com
4. joe@myclient.com
5. **bigboss@myclient.com -> Google Apps**

Let's say my client have a regular shared hosting plan on a major hosting company out there.

Everyone in the company accesses their emails using Roundcube regularly, but now Bigboss is willing to pay for a Google Apps for Business account for one of his emails, while keeping everyone else in Roundcube.

Can Bigboss do that? How?

Answer (score 1):

You have three options here.

1. Let Google Apps pull messages for `bigboss@myclient.com` from the legacy email system via IMAP/POP
2. Set up forwarding from the legacy system to Google Apps for `bigboss@myclient.com` (possibly leaving a copy in the legacy system, if you want)
3. Redirect the domain's MX records to point at Google Apps, and have Google Apps forward all mail *except* mail for `bigboss@myclient.com` to the legacy system (*split delivery*, this option is also described in [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/33276/21583))

Each option has some advantages and disadvantages. Firstly, if most/all email accounts are eventually going to be migrated to Google Apps, you should go with option 3 from the start.

Google has great documentation for these options, which is regularly updated. So instead of me posting the information here (which might possibly be outdated some day), follow Google's guide at https://gsuite.google.com/setup/resources/pilot/, and especially https://support.google.com/a/answer/178332.